# Data Array with empty multiple sub field check

Tags: php, arrays

I have an issue that my data array has around thousand record and some of data rows are like:

```
$data = array(
[0]=array("id"=>2,"name"=>'John',"status"=>1,"comment"=>""),
[1]=array("id"=>3,"name"=>'rock',"status"=>1),
[2]=array("id"=>4,"comment"=>""),
[3]=array("id"=>5,"name"=>'Jack',"status"=>1),
[4]=array("id"=>6,"name"=>'Scott',"status"=>0),
[5]=array("id"=>7,"name"=>'Nathan',"status"=>1),
[6]=array("id"=>8,"name"=>'locus',"status"=>1)
[7]=array("id"=>9,"comment"=>""),
[8]=array("id"=>10,"report"=>""),
[9]=array("id"=>12,"name"=>''),
[10]=array("id"=>20,"name"=>'Sairr',"status"=>1)
);
```

I just want to ignore all rows having sub field 1 like

> [7]=array("id"=>9)

Moy code:

```
foreach( $data as $field )
{
         //code
         //code
         //code
}
```

I have post sample data but my actual data is very large but have same case.
Thanks for advance.Please help me.

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: did you want to *ignore* it in a function or clean your $data array?

Comment: Yes i have written. Actually i have to generate pdf of that data and my code looks some thing like: I post it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof`/`count` functions will give you size (number of elements) of your array.

Use `array_filter`:

```
$data = array(
   array("id"=>2,"name"=>'John',"status"=>1),
   array("id"=>3,"name"=>'rock',"status"=>1),
   array("id"=>4),
   array("id"=>8,"name"=>'locus',"status"=>1),
   array("id"=>9),
   array("id"=>20,"name"=>'Sairr',"status"=>1),
);
$array = array_filter($data, function($v) { return 1 < sizeof($v); });
print_r($array);
```

Or simple `if`-condition:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (1 < count($item)) {
        print_r($item);
    }
}
```